# Append groups of random values to a list (Python)

Tags: python, list, random

I am trying to generate a list of values that append another list as parameter in the order shown below in the 'parameters' list.

How may I go about appending 'parameters' to 'vector' with random values upon each iteration of the for loop?

e.g. Desired output appending 'parameters' twice to 'vector'
[ 2, 14000, 120, 1, 12000, 80]

```
def generate_vector(self):
      parameters = [lambda:random.randint(0, 3), lambda:random.randint(0, 400000), lambda:random.randint(0, 128)]
      vector = []
      path, dirs, files = os.walk("templ_list/").next()
      file_count = len(files)

      for file in files:
          vector.append(parameters)
      return vector,
```

Comment: Please note that the parameters are parsed into the templates using a different function and that depending on the number of files in the directory then the for loop will loop x amount of times e.g. 10 files = 10 loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a generator for your Parameters and flatten the list with sum.

```
params_gen =  ((random.randint(0, 3), random.randint(0, 400000), random.randint(0, 128)) for _ in range(len(files)))
vector = sum(params_gen, ())
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for Pask. Thanks for your help dude :)

Comment: `params_gen`  creates an array which looks like this: `((1, 1000, 64), (3, 1200, 34))`
`sum` will then add the tuples resulting in:

 `() + (1, 1000, 64) + (3, 1200, 34) = (1, 1000, 64, 3, 1200, 34)`